# Problem Connecting QBluetoothSocket to multiple devices

Tags: c++, qt, esp32

I'm trying to use QBluetoothSocket to open (client) connections to two BT Classic SPP Servers. The SPP Servers run on two separate ESP32 devices which are paired with the PC already.

I wrote a Class to handle a SPP connection to a device with a known Bluetooth address. This works fine as long as I'm only trying to connect to a single device. If I try to start a connection to a second device with QBluetoothSocket::connectToService() the PC connects to the device ( connection is reported correctly on ESP32 side ). The problem is that the QBluetoothSocket stays in the "ConnectingState" and never calls the QBluetoothSocket::connected() signal for the second device.

I'm on a Linux system running BlueZ.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

For reference, this is the Class handling the connection:

```
#include <QtCore/qmetaobject.h>

#include "bclassichandler.h"

BTClassicHandler::BTClassicHandler( QObject *parent ) : QObject{ parent } {}

BTClassicHandler::~BTClassicHandler() {}

void BTClassicHandler::connect( const QBluetoothAddress &btAddr )
{
    if ( m_socket ) return;

    m_socket = new QBluetoothSocket( QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol );
    qDebug() << "Created Socket for " << btAddr.toString();

    qDebug() << "Connecting to SPP on " << btAddr.toString();

    QObject::connect( m_socket, &QBluetoothSocket::readyRead, this,
                      &BTClassicHandler::onSocketRead );
    QObject::connect( m_socket, &QBluetoothSocket::connected, this,
                      &BTClassicHandler::onSocketConnected );
    QObject::connect( m_socket, &QBluetoothSocket::disconnected, this,
                      &BTClassicHandler::onSocketDisconnected );
    QObject::connect( m_socket, &QBluetoothSocket::errorOccurred, this,
                      &BTClassicHandler::onSocketError );
    QObject::connect( m_socket, &QBluetoothSocket::stateChanged, this,
                      &BTClassicHandler::onStateChanged );

    setAddress( btAddr );

    m_socket->connectToService( btAddr, QBluetoothUuid::ServiceClassUuid::SerialPort );
}

void BTClassicHandler::disconnect()
{
    delete m_socket;
    m_socket = nullptr;
}

void BTClassicHandler::write( QString data ) {}

void BTClassicHandler::setAddress( const QBluetoothAddress &btAddr )
{
    m_btAddr = btAddr;
}

void BTClassicHandler::setAddress( QString btAddr )
{
    m_btAddr = QBluetoothAddress( btAddr );
}

QBluetoothAddress BTClassicHandler::getAddress()
{
    return m_btAddr;
}

bool BTClassicHandler::isConnected()
{
    if ( !m_socket ) return false;
    return ( m_socket->state() == QBluetoothSocket::SocketState::ConnectedState );
}

/* Private Slots */

void BTClassicHandler::onSocketConnected() // <<<<< THIS IS NEVER CALLED FOR THE SECOND DEVICE !!!!
{
    qDebug() << "Connected to " << m_btAddr.toString();
    emit sig_BTConnected( m_btAddr );
}

void BTClassicHandler::onSocketDisconnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected from " << m_btAddr.toString();
}

void BTClassicHandler::onSocketRead() {}

void BTClassicHandler::onSocketError( QBluetoothSocket::SocketError error )
{
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<QBluetoothSocket::SocketError>();
    QString errorString = metaEnum.valueToKey( static_cast<int>( error ) );

    qDebug() << "Socket Error " << m_btAddr.toString() << " :" << errorString;
}

void BTClassicHandler::onStateChanged( QBluetoothSocket::SocketState state )
{
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<QBluetoothSocket::SocketState>();
    QString stateString = metaEnum.valueToKey( static_cast<int>( state ) );

    qDebug() << "State Changed " << m_btAddr.toString() << " : " << stateString;
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm using the following versions:

QT 6.2.4

Bluez 5.5.3

Ubuntu 20.04

**EDIT:**

On further investigation I discovered, that Bluez indeed establishes a connection: bluetootctl and btmon report a connection and bluez also sends a connected message via DBus. Still the QT connected signal is not invoked.

**EDIT:**

To wrap this up: I didn't find a solution. As a workaround I wrote my own bluetooth socket class based on AF_BLUETOOTH linux sockets. This is done by QT for older Bluez Versions, too (<5.46). For inspiration look at QBluetoothSocketPrivateBluez class in qtConnectivity.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings, I am having the same problem now altough with a different Qt version (5)